# Bootstrap Modal not showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="continer">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <button class="btn btn-primary" target="#loginmodal" data-toggle="modal"></button>
         <div class="modal" id="loginmodal" tabindex="-1">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
               <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                     <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                     <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="Username">Username</label>
                           <input type="text" name="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="Password">Password</label>
                           <input type="Password" name="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target` attribute should be `data-target` on the button that triggers the modal to show. I'd also add `type="button"` to this button:

```
<div class="continer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#loginmodal" data-toggle="modal">Launch Modal</button>
            <div class="modal" id="loginmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="Username">Username</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="Password">Password</label>
                                    <input type="Password" name="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```